# How to configure Ansible to use my local SSH configuration?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm testing out Ansible and am already stuck on a fairly simple thing. I configured my `/etc/ansible/hosts` to contain the IP of my server:

```
[web]
1.2.3.4
```

Now, connecting to it with `ansible all -vvvv -m ping` fails since my `~/.ssh/config` for the specified server uses a custom port, a key file not in the default location, etc. How do I tell Ansible to reuse my SSH configuration for the connection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a little esoteric, so it's understandable you missed it. This is [from the Ansible Inventory page](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups):

> If you have hosts that run on non-standard SSH ports you can put the port number after the hostname with a colon. Ports listed in your SSH config file won’t be used with the paramiko connection but will be used with the openssh connection.
>
> To make things explicit, it is suggested that you set them if things are not running on the default port

So, in your case:

```
[web]
1.2.3.4:9000
```

(Using `9000` as your alt port, of course)

[Ansible uses paramiko on systems with a dated version of ssh](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_getting_started.html#remote-connection-information), such as CentOS/RHEL.

Comment: Ok, so that's the port, how about the IdentityFile? I use a different key for all my hosts, is there a way to specify those? I really thought Ansible would be smart enough to figure out all these configuration options from my `~/.ssh/config` rather than duplicating all of the info.

Comment: Ah, just noticed the link you pasted, very helpful. My correct config was `example ansible_ssh_port=777 ansible_ssh_host=1.2.3.4 ansible_ssh_user=martin ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/martin/example/id_rsa`. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

What tedder42 said plus there are other slightly more advanced ways of defining your ssh config on a per host basis.

```
[web]
1.2.3.4 ansible_ssh_port=9000
```

This only makes sense if you're also using the other ansible_ssh special variables like ansible_ssh_user and ansible_ssh_host.

ansible_ssh_host is helpful if you want to be able to refer to a server by a name of your choosing instead of its IP.

```
[web]
apache ansible_ssh_host=1.2.3.4 ansible_ssh_port=9000
```

If you end up with multiple hosts with the same alternative ssh port you can makes use of Ansible's group variable function.

```
[web]
1.2.3.4 
5.6.7.8
9.10.11.12

[web:vars]
ansible_ssh_port=9000
```

Now Ansible will use port 9000 on all three of the hosts In the web group.

Understanding how to organize your inventory data goes a long way to your success with Ansible.